# Can I use a SVG toolbar icon?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I use an SVG file for a toolbar icon instead of creating PNG files in several sizes?

I read the following in the Chrome Developer documentation for the browserAction icon:

> Static images can be in any format WebKit can display, including BMP, GIF, ICO, JPEG, or PNG. For unpacked extensions, images must be in the PNG format.

-- [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#icon)

Since WebKit supports SVG images, it stands to reason that I would be able to use an SVG icon. The lack of support for unpacked extensions seems odd, but it's easy enough to pack my extension.

Unfortunately, after I pack my extension and try to install it by dragging it to the Extensions tab in Chrome, it says `Could not decode image: logo.svg`...

[image: extension error message]

Image is very simple. I created it in Inkscape and saved it using "Save as type: Plain SVG (*.svg).

Comment: https://crbug.com/29683

Comment: @wOxxOm I read that before I posted my question, but I didn't think it was related. It's for an unpacked extension and the [extension icons](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/user_interface#icons). My question is about a packed extension and the [browserAction icon](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#icon). Regarding your comment 49... No. Not anyone can submit a patch to Chromium and the first line of the document you linked says why.

Comment: What does the first line say to you? I know for a fact that anyone can contribute code to chromium and people do, although rarely.

Comment: @wOxxOm `you already have a working checkout and build. A full checkout pulls many other repositories such as v8 and Skia which have their own repositories and processes` Chromium's build alone has high system requirements, needs a specific version of Visual Studio ($499), and familiarity with a complex build process. Just learning the build process would take weeks of dedication. There's a lot more, but I was already disqualified by the system requirements. Anyone can submit a patch to Chromium in the same sense that anyone can submit a paper on theoretical physics to a respected journal.

Comment: You're exaggerating. I'm not good at championing obvious things but here goes nothing: you don't have to use VS or Windows, you can use Linux or a Linux subsystem in Windows. All the requirements are sane and typical for a large project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use SVG as a toolbar icon and you need to generate a png of different sizes.

Comment: But why? What is the reason?

Comment: @DxTx probably outdated tech?!

Comment: as noted in comments to the question, it's Chrome bug logged here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29683 you can "star" it to increase chances this to be fixed

Comment: while adding a star *should* help, it's been outstanding since Dec 8, 2009 - so seems unlikely anything will change

Comment: When adding the svg as a web_accessible_resource in manifestV3, and dynamically setting, I can load SVGs.

Comment: FF now supports the SVG https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/icons#svg